# How do I switch from ubuntu to windows?

Tags: partitioning, windows, 22.04

So I want to switch from ubuntu 22.04 LTS back to windows 11. I am single booting my pc. Ive been trying to find some tutorials on google and youtube, but i havent found anything good. Please give me step to step process how to install windows(How to make a bootable usb(i have a usb),format partitions etc.)

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you asking on an Ubuntu site about installing Windows? Just install Windows over Ubuntu. Go to Windows’ / Microsoft’s website and follow their instructions.

Comment: @Will Im really sorry if this isnt the right place. But ive asked  here because I dont  even know how to format an usb in linux and how to format partitions

Comment: You don't need to format partitions in Ubuntu, you just boot the OS you want to install (*in this case windows*) and it'll do everything you want which is erasing & installing the new OS.   To create a bootable windows USB, it's best to follow Microsoft documentation which expects you to use a windows PC or pre-purchase a USB with windows on it (You don't need to format a USB prior to writing an ISO to it!)

Comment: before you ask the next question do a backup of your important files if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

**If you have another computer on Windows you can:**

1. Download Windows 11 from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11).
2. Download Rufus from [rufus.ie](https://rufus.ie) and open it.
3. Insert your USB Drive & select your device in Rufus device dropdown.
4. Under boot selection, press select and navigate to your ISO & double click it.
5. Make sure "Installation option" is set to "Standard Windows Installation" & make sure partition scheme is set to "GPT"
6. After, press start to flash the ISO to the USB.
7. Boot up from the flash drive and perform your Windows install

**If you don't have another computer:**

1. Download Windows 11 from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11).
2. Download balenaEtcher from [balena.io](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).
3. In your file manager right-click the .AppImage you just downloaded from balena.io and go to properties.
4. In properties, check the tabs for a checkbox that says something like "Is executable" and make sure it's checked.
5. **OR:** open your terminal and CD to the directory where your .AppImage is stored and run `chmod +x ./<balenaEtcher-file>.AppImage`
6. Then run it using `./<balenaEtcher-file>.AppImage` in your terminal or double click it in your file manager.
7. In balenaEtcher select the ISO you just downloaded from Microsoft and select your USB drive then press "Flash" and wait for it to finish.
8. Once done, you can restart, insert your drive and perform your Windows install